# How to create a form from a json file in extjs

Tags: json, forms, extjs

I have a json file simular to this:

```
[{
"name": "testReport",
"type": "Intern",
"description": "Test report for extjs",
"query": "select DATE(sa.startTime)",
"queryFields": [{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "STRING",
    "format": null,
    "many": false
}, {
    "name": "from",
    "type": "DATE",
    "format": "yyyyMMdd",
    "many": false
}, {
    "name": "to",
    "type": "DATE",
    "format": "yyyyMMdd",
    "many": false
}]
```

In a grid i show the name, type and description. When you click on a button i want to open a new window what is working. But what i need is to open the window and generate a form based on the queryFields. So when i click on the testreport i need to have a textfield(name), a datefield(from) and a datefield(to). Is this possible? And how do i do this :$

Comment: We got the idea... What have _you_ tried? I think you really need to look through ExtJs manual and samples and try to do something

Answer (score 0):

Use a SelectionModel (maybe a CheckBoxSelectionModel). The user will select the row they want by checking the check boxes of the rows. Then when they click the display reports button you can use the SelectionModel to find all the selected records and pass the records on to your form which which you can use to create the form or fill the forms fields in whichever you need.

My advice is to look at the API for

1. GridPanels
2. SelectionModels
3. Record

Then design it when you have an understanding of these concepts.